# Does Red Alert 2 support TCP?

Tags: networking, command-and-conquer-red-alert-2

The original Red Alert 2 did not support networked multiplayer over TCP/IP and instead used IPX.

Does the current RA2 offering on EA's [Origin](https://www.origin.com/nld/en-us/store/command-and-conquer/command-and-conquer-the-ultimate-collection) the  as part "C&C The Ultimate Collection" support network gaming over TCP/IP and WAN?

There is a remastered version of C&C in the [works](https://www.ea.com/games/command-and-conquer/command-and-conquer-remastered/features?isLocalized=true) which is not related to this question.

Comment: Considering the digital version of RA2 hardly works due to its DRM kicking in, I highly doubt EA actually put in any kind of effort when re-releasing it.

Comment: as an alternative you could just play from here https://cncnet.org/red-alert-2 - it has online support

Comment: Thank you but that link requires the original RA2 game of which I am not in possesion.

Comment: @Levon Basically, you buy the game on Origin, and then apply the CnCNet installer, which patches it to switch it from IPX to TCP. And the remaster is unrelated to RA2 altogether since it only contains the first two games.